# $wp_rewrite->flush_rules() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, hook

I'm building a Wordpress plugin that sets up a custom post type, and it all seems to be working fine and dandy. However, I have an activation hook that should (in theory at least) set up my permalinks and flush my rewrite rules, but it doesn't work:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'foodsafety_activate' );

function foodsafety_activate() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%inspection%", '([^/]+)', "inspection=");
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('inspection', $inspection_structure, false);    
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

If I go into `Settings > Permalinks` and hit 'Save changes' the rules get flushed and the permalinks work as expected, so I must be going wrong somewhere with the activation hook. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you copied all your function code?
Because, it seems that $inspection_structure is empty..

Comment: Ah, you're right. I copied and pasted the code from somewhere without thinking! It does seem that `add_permastruct` isn't too well documented though. Any ideas as to what should be put there?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the register_activation_hook( **FILE**, 'foodsafety_activate' ); is in the main plugin file? I had the same issue. It turned out that register activation only works when placed in main plugin file.